# Class variables not callable?

Tags: python, class, variables

I've stumbled on what is probably a simple issue but I struggle to think of a solution.
If I try to make a class variable that equates to a number or an array index they come up with these errors

```
'int' object is not callable
```

and

```
'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

---

```
class Do_something:
   def __init__(self,number = 0):
      self.number = number
      self.result = 1 + self.number

something = Do_something()
print(something.result(1))
```

---

```
import numpy as np

class Do_something_else:

   def __init__(sel):
      self.arr = np.zeros([5,5])
      self.index = self.arr[0]

something = Do_something_else()
print(something.index())
```

This seems odd since I can set variables equal to ints and arrays elsewhere.
What am I missing and what is the solution?

Comment: It doesn't seem odd, it is how it's supposed to work. Why are you trying to execute a number or a numpy array? They are not methods, they are attributes from your class. That's why you cannot call them like functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both piece of code `result` and `index` are not methods, they are instance valiables.
To make this code work it should look like this:

```
class Do_something:
   def __init__(self,number = 0):
      self.number = number
      self.result = 1 + self.number

something = Do_something(1)
print(something.result)
```

and

```
class Do_something_else:

   def __init__(self):
      self.arr = np.zeros([5,5])
      self.index = self.arr[0]

something = Do_something_else()
print(something.index)
```

Also pay attention that there ia s misspelling in `def __init__(sel):` line in `Do_something_else` class. It should be `def __init__(self):`